# Different answers for same code in c

Tags: c, gcc, g++

What happens in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int e;
    printf("%d ", e);
    printf("%s", e);
    return 0;
}
```

Does e will have
a) Garbage value?
b) NULL

In GCC it shows garbage value and in g++ it shows 0 and NULL.
Thanks!!

Comment: What do you think? That said, g++ is part of the GCC, so what is your question really?

Comment: Correct answer: c) **dragons**

Comment: It could be [worse than dragons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108). However, if you compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` you'll be warned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both statements invoke undefined behavior because `e` object is not initialized so its value is indeterminate.

The second statement also has the wrong conversion specifier, `%s` specification requires a `char *` argument.

So as someone mentioned in the comments, the correct answer is neither a) nor b) but c) *demons flying out your nose*.

Answer (score 5):

This program invokes undefined behavior. You are using wrong format specifier for `int` data type in second `printf` statement. Do not expect any good. Also note that `e` is not initialized and its value is indeterminate.

Answer (score 0):

This program when compiled generated warning:

*warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char*’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
 printf("%s", e);*

And in both cases it generates garbage values.

**gcc :**

[image]

**g++** :

[image]